# BizTalk, WCF-SAP adapter and load balancing

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have two BizTalk 2010 servers that belong to the same BizTalk group. They are being used to expose a web service front-end to SAP BAPI calls. A load balancer sits in front of the two BizTalk servers for the web service requests. If both BizTalk servers are active, I get session errors when calling BAPIs that modify data. The first call on the first server succeeds, but a second call that is serviced by the other server fails with a session error when the BAPI_COMMIT_TRANSACTION message is sent to SAP. This also has the side-effect of leaving an open transaction in SAP and locking the records.

Has anybody else seen this behavior? Is the WCF-SAP adapter limited to only one active instance like the FTP adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. 
BAPI transactions rely on the different BAPI calls going over the same physical connection to SAP.
So, you can't laod balence SAP adapter insatances doing BAPI transactinos.

For scale, you will have look into same way of partinitoning which can achive sticky-routing.